# Is my 2 year old's speech on-par?

Tags: toddler, speech

I am concerned that my 25 month old son's speech may not be on par. Most of his sentences consists of a noun and a verb. For example: *Daddy eat* or *mommy swim*.

He also mispronounces certain words while others come out perfectly clear.

Is this normal at that age? I know another couple with a 23 month old who is forming very clear sentences.

Comment: When we look at other children we often worry that ours is somehow slower or develops worsely. Most often our worries are groundless. Each child develops in its own pace. We should do our best to remember that - yes, I find it difficult too. And besides, in the end, it doesn't really matter that much how smart or skillful our child is - it's what kind of person it becomes.

Comment: It is useful to identify problems with speech early so that people can get early intervention.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes, it's normal.**  The speed of speech development varies widely, but all that's expected from a two-to-three year-old is that they form two-word phrases and speak sufficiently comprehensibly to be understood by their parents, which your son seems to be doing just fine.  Boys also tend to be slower to pick up speech than girls.  Here's a [handy milestone chart](https://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/voice/pages/speechandlanguage.aspx) from the US Dept of Health.

Answer (score 3):

The literature on grammar acquisition distinguishes the following three stages.

1. One-word stage (e.g., "mama", "papa" "water", "poop"...)
2. Two-word stage (e.g., "want cookie", "flower blue",...)
3. For everyday purposes, adult-like grammatical competence.

In reality, the big jump is transitioning from the one-word stage to the two-word stage. One your kid reaches the two-word stage, the move to full sentences might take some time to start, but once it starts, it will happen surprisingly quickly.